# RegEx Replaces Duplicate Character Sequences but Removes Dots and Commas Entirely (but Shouldn't)

Tags: c++, regex, regex-replace

I'm trying to write a regex for replacing sequential occurrence of specified characters with single ones. I used a backreference and character class for that. However, some of the characters (`.` and `,`, in my case) just get completely removed (and I cannot figure out what I've missed).

**Question:** Why does it work that way?

**Note:** I'm using `C++20`.

```
std::string s{ "...?12 :: 54  ! !! ..,,,- ---" };
const std::regex re("([.,\\-:!?]){2,}");
s = std::regex_replace(s, re, "$1");
```

I expected to get `.?12 : 54  ! ! .,- -`, but, instead, I get `?12 : 54  ! ! - -`. Escaping `.` and `,` didn't help either.

Comment: Are you trying to match the `-` character, or the range of characters from `\ ` to `:`?

Comment: `([.,\\-:!?]){2,}` matches 2 or more matches of the character set. So it matches all 4 characters `...?` at the beginning. It captures the last one, so the replacement is `?`.

Comment: Are you trying to match a sequence of identical characters?

Comment: Barmar, yes. Consequences of identical characters should be replaced with single ones.

Comment: Use a capture group with a back-reference: `([...])\\1+` to match the same character.

Comment: I'm not writing an answer because I'm sure there are duplicates, but I haven't been able to find a good one for C++.

Comment: Barmar, thank you so much! Your comment (I upwoted it) solves a problem. Please, do post it as the answer.

Comment: Interesting backreference magic.

Comment: it's basically what backreferences were created for.

Comment: Barmar, I just cannot figure out why `\\1+` works, but `\\1{2,}` doesn't.

Comment: That will only match when the character is at least 3 times in a row. `([...])` matches the first one, and `\\1(2,)` matches at least 2 more.

Comment: So it will match `...` but not `..`

Comment: I'm going to suggest that even if it results in (marginally) more complex C++ code, a small loop to handle this will be a whole lot clearer than the regex involved in implementing it this way.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I agree with you, but I wanted to have a single line solution.

Comment: @Barmar, I think I got the idea. Thank you for your explanations!

Comment: @ENIAC: `remove_consecutive_dupes(some_string, ".,\-:!?");` ;-) Seriously though, "single line" seems like a terrible criterion to me.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I thought it was a C++ function, at first. LOL :) I'm the only contributor to my project, so that "terrible-look" solution is OK for me.